# MySQL Seperator Error

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been trying to use the SEPERATOR function on a SQL query but it gives me a syntax error, why?

```
SELECT e.*, GROUP_CONCAT(mgl.genre_title, mgl.genre_id SEPERATOR "-") AS genres FROM events e 
LEFT JOIN music_genres_link mgl ON e.id = mgl.event_id 
WHERE e.id = 1
GROUP BY e.id
```

I simply wish for it to do:

55-Electronic, 23-Trance

Instead of:

55Electronic, 23Trance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want:

```
SELECT e.*,
       GROUP_CONCAT(mgl.genre_title, '-', mgl.genre_id) as genres
FROM events e LEFT JOIN
     music_genres_link mgl
     ON e.id = mgl.event_id 
WHERE e.id = 1
GROUP BY e.id;
```

Notes:

- `SEPARATOR`, not `SEPERATOR`.
- The separator is for the values for different rows.  For the values within a row, you need to add it manually in the `GROUP_CONCAT()`.
- As you seem to know, `GROUP_CONCAT()` takes multiple arguments.
- If you are selecting one event, then the `GROUP BY` is unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you once again Gordon!

Answer (score 3):

I suspect the syntax error is because you have misspelled it. You need [SEPARATOR](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group_concat/).

Answer (score 2):

Group concat don't need comma between columns ..
if you need  group_concat for concat values the you should use concat inside the grou_concat function for join the columns

```
  SELECT e.*, GROUP_CONCAT(concat(mgl.genre_title, mgl.genre_id)  SEPARATOR "-") AS genres 
  FROM events e 
  LEFT JOIN music_genres_link mgl ON e.id = mgl.event_id 
  WHERE e.id = 1
  GROUP BY e.id
```

and SEPARATOR  .. Too